# Obvious security flaws in redirect?

Tags: html, servlets, video, https, security

I have a web app that stores videos. I am using a java servlet (over https) which verifies a username and password. Once the details are verified, i redirect the user to a video stored in AWS S3. For those who don't know how S3 works, its just a web service that stores objects (basically think of it as storing files). It also uses https. Now obviously to make this work, the s3 object (file) is public. I've given it a random name full of numbers and letters.

So the servlet basically looks like this:

```
void doGet(request, response){
   if (authenticateUser(request.getParameter("Username"), request.getParameter("Password")){
      response.sendRedirect("https://s3.amazonaws.com/myBucket/xyz1234567.mp4");
   }
}
```

This is obviously simplified but it gets the point across. Are there any very obvious security flaws here? The video tag will obviously have a source of something like https://www.mysite.com/getVideo?Username="Me"&Password="randomletters". At first blush it seems like it should be as secure as anything else assuming i give the file names sitting at AWS s3 sufficiently random names?

Answer (score 3):

The obvious security flaw is that anybody could detect which URL the authentication servlet redirects to, and share this URL with all his friends, thus allowing anyone to access the resource directly, without going through the euthentication servlet.

Unfortunately, I don't know S3 at all, so I can't recommend any fix to the security problem.

Comment: When you say "anybody", what do you mean exactly? I'm having users log into my site with a username and password. The video tag is generated by javascript and has the username and password added as parameters (I should have added this in the original post). So, a user could technically do what you are saying, but they could also just give out their password to all their friends. From a practical perspective, what would a security flaw be?

Comment: If a user gives his password to everyone, you can notice, at server side, that the same account loads a whole lot of videos from many different IPs, and block this account. If anybody is able to access videos without login, you can't block anyone, and the login is useless. Knowing the actual URL of the video is just a metter of hitting F12 in the browser, go to the network tab, and see what HTTP requests are executed.

Comment: I don't think that a dynamically loaded <video src='https://blahblahblah/filname'> will be stored in history. In this case the user has no incentive to give out links, urls etc, its their data they are uploading and want to keep private. Am I wrong about the history?

Comment: @user: Yes, getting the URL is a piece of cake. Even a non-technical user can do it using just the browser.

Answer (score 0):

All this mechanism does is provide a very limited obfuscation - using developer tools in most modern browsers (or a proxy such as Fiddler) a user will be able to watch the URL of the video that's being loaded and, if it's in a Public S3 bucket, then simply share the link.

With S3 your only real solution would be to secure the bucket and then either require that the user is logging in or use the temporary tokens for access [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html] ... though this does complicate your solution

I would also mention that including the password and username in plaintext on the link to the video asset (from the question above) is very insecure